# Error installing CRM module

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am unable to install the crm module in odoo10. when trying to install CRM module displays the following error.

Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 675, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 331, in _call_function
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 119, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 324, in checked_call
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 933, in **call**
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 889, in call_button
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 877, in _call_kw
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 681, in call_kw
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 672, in call_kw_multi
     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\base\module\module.py", line 410, in button_immediate_install
     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\base\module\module.py", line 484, in _button_immediate_function
     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 82, in new
     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 339, in load_modules
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 237, in load_marked_modules
     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 159, in load_module_graph
         File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 95, in _load_data
          File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 845, in convert_file
           File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 915, in convert_xml_import
         File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 796, in parse
         File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 799, in parse
          File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 707, in _tag_record
          File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_model.py", line 1228, in _update
          File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\calendar\models\calendar.py", line 1432, in create
          File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\calendar\models\calendar.py", line 936, in create_attendees
           File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\calendar\models\calendar.py", line 164, in _send_mail_to_attendees
           File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\mail\models\mail_template.py", line 560, in send_mail
        File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\fetchmail\models\mail_mail.py", line 18, in create
        File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\mail\models\mail_mail.py", line 65, in create
       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3830, in create
         File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3891, in _create
         File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\mail\models\mail_message.py", line 720, in create
         File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\mail\models\mail_message.py", line 699, in _get_message_id
        File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\tools\mail.py", line 431, in generate_tracking_message_id
ParseError: "ascii
PROGRAMA\xc7\xc3O20
8
9
ordinal not in range(128)" while parsing file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Odoo%2010.0/server/odoo/addons/calendar/data/calendar_demo.xml:17, near
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the demo data. While creating a new database do not check the demo data(chekbox).

Comment: SFX thank you very much for your response, but now throw another error, create a new database and when I try to install the CRM module it says this:                                                                                                  
ordinal not in range(128)" while parsing file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Odoo%2010.0/server/odoo/addons/crm/data/mail_template_data.xml:119, near
<function id="mail_template_function_module_install_crm" model="mail.template" name="send_mail" eval="[ref('mail_template_data_module_install_crm'), ref('base.module_crm')]"/>